# Kitchen converge stuck at Preparing client.rb

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

A fresh run of `kitchen converge` runs fine. However, the second run halts at `preparing client.rb`

...[image]

Has anyone ever encountered this issue? How should I debug this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I was doing this with vagrant (1.8.1) and kitchen (1.5.0). [denniss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364253/denniss) in his answer above, was mucking around with the 'sudo' group in his answer above and so was I. To fix that, I added the default "vagrant" user to the sudo group in my user recipe as follows replacing the old members() line with the new one which adds "vagrant" to the group (even though this recipe is not managing the "vagrant" user).

```
#  . . . /myapp/recipes/users_recipe.rb
#
include_recipe "users"
group 'sudo'

user 'jgodse' do
  action :lock
  group 'sudo'
  system true
  shell '/bin/bash'
  home '/home/jgodse'
  manage_home true
  password '$1$xyz$35Ph9JlxB.1tGXqrCgX5y0' 
end
group 'sudo' do
  action :modify
  ###  members ["jgodse","sysadministrator"]    ###old code
  members ["jgodse","sysadministrator", "vagrant"]  #new code
  append true
end
```

Comment: +1 to help to identify my issue. But I don't think it's the cleaner fix. The configuration about vagrant user should be kept in .kitchen.yml configuration (provisioner.attributes.authorization...) to not pollute the main recipe.

Answer (score 2):

I was messing around with `/etc/sudoers` and revoked sudo access to root user. I decided to just add the user to `gid "sudo"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. The best way is solving that using kitchen. In my case add to my `.kitchen.yml` file these attributes:

```
attributes:
  authorization:
    sudo:
      passwordless: true
      include_sudoers_d: true
```

If you don't want to affect all the users you can choose specific users using `members`. I recommend to use this option because it keeps your recipes agnostic.